# calculating the limit of $\int_0^1 \frac{n \cos(x)}{1+x^2n^{1.5}}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals, solution-verification

i want to calculate $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \frac{n \cos(x)}{1+x^2n^{1.5}}dx$$ I think this integral is bounded from below by $$n\int_0^1\frac{\cos(1)}{1+x^2n^{1.5}}dx$$ and this equals $n^{0.75}\tan^{-1}{n^{0.75}}\cos(1)$ that goes to infinity so the limit of the main integral is infinity.

Am I correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Indeed the integrand is positive and the integral on the interval $(0,n^{-1/10})$ is already at least $n^{9/10}$ plus some lower order terms, hence yes the integrals converge to $+\infty$ when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @Did u mean i am true?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222933/limit-of-the-integral-int-01-fracn-cos-x1x2n3-2-dx

Answer (score 0):

It's true that the integrals tend to $\infty$, but in your argument, you miscalculated $n\int_0^1 \frac{\cos(1)\, dx}{1 + x^2n^{1.5}}$. You should get $n^{\color{red}{0.25}}\arctan(n^{0.75})\cos(1)$. This is just a minor error -- it still tends to $\infty$.